# How to upgrade from java 6 version 20 to java 6 version 23 in ubuntu 10.10 [Maverick Meerkat]?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

when i check for the java version in the shell i got the following output:

```
X@X-desktop:~$  java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.2) (6b20-1.9.2-0ubuntu2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
X@X-desktop:~$
```

Comment: There is a reason this site was made. Your email is unnecessary, and shouldn't be included in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and `sudo apt-get upgrade` in that order.